# Why Ajax.BeginForm redirect to new empty page after submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Why Ajax.BeginForm redirect my page to new empty page after submission?

My controller code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ProductCommentAdd(int productId, string text)
    {
           //Do something
    }
```

Mvc ajax call in view is:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProductCommentAdd", "Shop", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST"}))
    {
                <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ProductId" name="ProductId"/>
                <textarea name="text"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"
    }
```

When I click submit button my page redirect to new empty page. How I can fix it?

Comment: Have you the vision "ProductCommentAdd"?

Comment: Are you sure the `unobtrusive.ajax.js` file is included in the page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need to include the following script to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" 
                       type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Mat J and @user3206982 suggests: you probably need the unobtrusive.ajax.js file.

You can download the package from nuget and 
add it in the bundles config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

and in the html:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive")
```

Source: https://dotnetthoughts.net/mvc5-ajax-form-is-not-updating-div-but-replacing-the-whole-page-instead/