# Prevent MVC JsonResult redirect to new page with Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My view code is as below

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendAmount", "Amount", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post", onSuccess="successcallback" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-12">
            <label>Amount</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-12">
            @Html.TextBox("txtAmount",null)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller Code

```
public JsonResult SendAmount()
{
      //Process flow
      return new JsonResult
      {
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        Data = new { result = "success" }
      };
 }
```

The problem is once the controller done calling  , it will redict to a new page with the json result **{"result":"success"}** instead of stay in the same page.

I know that it can be achieve by using Jquery ajax call , but i would like to know is that possible to do it with MVC and controller.

Comment: Your using the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper so what do you expect, look to the `successCallback` to see why it's redirecting to a new page.

Comment: The action name present in the form is `SendAmount` but your `JsonResult` action is `DepositRequest`, could you provide more details? Also client-side `successcallback` function is still not provided yet.

Comment: See if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787840. You might have to include jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: @abc cba, actually your requirement is not clear. Are you wanting to redirect to new page from `DepositRequest()` if operation is success?

Comment: Http works by sending `request` and receiving `response`. When you submit a form, you're sending a request, after processing it in your server, it returns as a response. If you haven't particularly tuned your code, the browser will display the response as it is in the page with the URL of the request, and that is why you're getting only the `{"result":"success"}` in your browser.

Comment: Yes you could use window.location = ".." to redirect via JS code response... I don't know how that works with AJAX.BeginForm, but works with a form tag and jQuery AJAX call.

Comment: @StevenManuel's suggestion is worked. I successfully reproduced the OP's problem [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1JxpLZ) and while adding `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` in a `<script>` tag then `successcallback` executed properly as in [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Iol8d). I considered to close this problem as dupe of that link.